# Posting data to get response using Retrofit

Tags: php, android, retrofit, retrofit2

How can i get response body after posting data to server using Retrofit2?

Here is my Interface:

```
public interface UserClient {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(Constants.REGISTRATION_URL)
    Call<UserData> createAccount(
           @FieldMap Map<String, Object> map
    );
}
```

Here is my method in MainActivity class:

```
 private void createUserForm(String username, String password, String email, String deviceID, String gender, String avatarPath, int online){
        UserClient userClient = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("username", username);
        map.put("password", password);

        Call<UserData> call = userClient.createAccount(map);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserData> call, Response<UserData> response) {
                // Need to get data from server after user has been inserted in database
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserData> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And this is my PHP class

```
<?php
    include '../db/db.php';
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, '$username',  '$password', '$email', '$device_id', '$gender', '$avatar_path', '$online')")){
     $loginQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND device_id = '".$device_id."' LIMIT 1 ");
      $row = mysqli_fetch_row($loginQuery);

        $userData['user_info'] = array(array(
            'id'       => $row[0],
            'username' => $row[1],
            'password'     => $row[2]
        ));

        print(json_encode($userData));
    }else{
        print(json_encode(null));
    }

?>
```

Flow :

- Inserting data to Mysql Database. (Works)
- Response in body also successful (Works)
- Sending Encoded data from php (Not Works)
- Trying to get encoded data from php in `onResponse` (Not Works)

Answer (score 0):

To send the encoded data try to use:

```
echo json_encode(['userData'=> $userData]);
```

To retrieve the data, you can implement the `Parcelable` interface in your model. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please post your model implementing Parcelable. You need to map the fields correctly to make it work...